# How to get information about table usage in DB2?

Tags: db2

I need to know the followings for all the tables in a schema:

1. How many times a table has been accessed (by accessed I mean SELECT queries explicitly, not INSERT or UPDATE as I am curious about usage
   activity by end users). If it is a single record per select query run, it is perfect.
2. When these SELECTS happened, and/or when was the last select
3. Who are the people running the select queries

This is a DB2 Warehouse on IBM Cloud.

I do not have admin rights to this warehouse and the actual db admin is not really helpful so I need to provide him a query so he can extract the data I need. I can't try things on my own .

I sent him this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY
WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'my_schema'
```

But it only returned table drop and reorg activities.

Comment: That's called "audit", look it up in the docs.

Comment: [Usage lists](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-usage-list) can help you as well.

Comment: This question is more suitable for dba.stackexchange.com.